# can i send data to a javascript function on the server iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I i'm wondering if it is possible to call a javascript function from my application. The js function is on the server. Let's say i have a some inputs in the app. Then i have this submit button which calls the IBAction, from the IBAction i want to call:

```
function mySubmit(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

and pass it the data the user entered and then get back a response (in my app) not in the server

Is this possible to do? if so, can you provide some useful links?

Thanks in advance and have a nice saturday ;)

Comment: So you want to fetch a whole HTML document, render it and cause that function to be called? I have a feeling there's probably a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do, maybe you could describe more what is the big picture of what you are wanting to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The js function is on the server

Are you sure this is your case? Don't you mean that your js submits a form that is itself treated on the server side?
Javascript is normally a client-side scripting language, which is executed on client-side, contrary to e.g. PHP which is only executed server-side.

*[EDIT] (As stated by @Dr.Dredel in the comments, as there exists server-side javascript, but these usages are not yet very common and I don't think it corresponds to your context)*

If you need to call a javascript function from an already loaded HTML page in a WebView, you can simply use the UIWebView's `stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:`. You can pass a string representing javascript code to this function, so you can build a string that represent a function call with string or int arguments for example without any problem.

But if you intend to load your HTML page just to call a javascript fonction which in turn submit a form that sends the form's data to your server… This is clearly the wrong way!

**You should instead considering performing the NSURLRequest to your server directly in Objective-C** (maybe **using `ASIHTTPRequest` to perform a POST request** and easily set the values for each keys of the form you intend to send). In addition, doing this directly in ObjC will avoid loading the HTML page for nothing and rely on the js script, and will allow you to directly get the response in the delegate method.

Comment: Ali, javascript is no longer exclusively on the client. Check out the Node project.  I don't think this question applies, but if you're going to answer questions, you probably shouldn't start with a profoundly incorrect premise in your opening sentence :)

Comment: Yeah you're right, sorry ;) I didn't know about the Node.js project, actually. But I think @madcoderz's question was about standard js use on client side, so I think starting to explain that in some contexts -- that are not related to his own use case -- js may be on server side, etc... will add some confusion ;) (Regarding the way he asked the question I guess he is confused enough already :D)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel : I just edited my post to take your comment into account, thx ;)